# low level diagnostics for audio

Tags: windows-10, audio, diagnostic

My laptop's internal speaker has stopped playing sound.  I have no problem with audio over bluetooth.

Other than reinstalling sound drivers (which I've done), is there any diagnostic tool that I can use that will allow me to see if it's a hardware issue or a software issue?

Answer (score 1):

My gut feeling is that it is not hardware.  If the onboard sound chip was not working properly, you would most likely not be receiving Bluetooth audio.  However, there is a small possibility this is not the case.

The first thing I would do is connect a pair of headphones or speakers to the audio out/speaker jack (assuming you have one).  If it works that heavily indicates that the sound chip is working.  However, it is not 100% proof, that its not a hardware issue.

Next I would download a Linux distro like [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and make a live USB [bootable flash drive](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview).  Boot off of it and see if your sound works properly by going to YouTube or some other sound producing whatnot.  If your sound does works properly, then it is definitely a software/driver/configuration issue in Windows 10.  You could ask here, or elsewhere, on how to resolve the issue.  However, that is not the question being asked.  Alternatively, you can [reset/refresh Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12415) or do a fresh install of Windows.

If you have the same issue while in the live Linux environment, then it most probably is a hardware issue. If it is a hardware issue, then it gets tricky to resolve.  You will need to open your laptop up.  First check to make sure the speaker is properly connected.  Perhaps the connector to the motherboard is loose and simply needs to be re-plugged in.  Also, it is possible a wire was poorly soldered to the speaker and has broken loose due to vibration.  If those are not the issue, you could use a multimeter to see if there is a voltage changes going to the speaker terminals when playing audio.  You could even plug in/connect a small speaker to the speaker connection on the motherboard to listen for sound.  If you see voltage changes or hear sound, the speaker has gone bad and will need to be replaced.  Anything past that, is more of an electrical repair/engineering question and is out of scope for this site.  At this point, you should contact the laptop manufacturer or possibly a computer repair shop that specializes in electrical repair.